# Passing list of file paths in variable as arguments to command

Tags: bash, kde, command-line-arguments, escape-characters, escaping

**Scenario:**

`kdialog --menu` takes a list of strings of the form `title element label element label ...`. Now, the issue with this is that spaces are used as delimiters.

Let's say I have a string variable $LIST containing a list of file paths and labels generated by another command. I want to make kdialog use the elements from that variable. Here are three ways the list could be formatted inside the variable:

`file A /dir/file A file B /dir/file B file C /dir/file C`

Obviously this is useless because there is no distinction between spaces inside filenames and delimiting spaces.

`"file A" "/dir/file A" "file B" "/dir/file B" "file C" "/dir/file C"`

If I try to use this with `kdialog --menu title $LIST` it doesn't work, because kidalog simply ignores the quotes. The same is true if I use `${LIST}` or `` `echo $LIST` `` or `$(echo $LIST)` The list of labels it will actually show in the produced menu will always be

```
A"
A"
B"
B"
C"
C"
```

Using `"$LIST"` on the other hand produces an error.

`file\ A /dir/file\ A file\ B /dir/file\ B file\ C /dir/file\ C`

The effect of this is exactly analogous to the quotes case, except in this case I can use "$LIST" to produce an equally useless result without error.

**Question:**

How can I pass a variable with a list of string elements, each of which may or may not contain spaces, to a command so that each element is interpreted as a separate argument by the command, but with escaped spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something to parse a single string and create multiple arguments from it. This is exactly a job for `xargs`. Like this:

```sh
LIST='"file A" "/dir/file A" "file B" "/dir/file B" "file C" "/dir/file C"'
printf '%s\n' "$LIST" | xargs kdialog --menu title
```

or

```sh
LIST='file\ A /dir/file\ A file\ B /dir/file\ B file\ C /dir/file\ C'
printf '%s\n' "$LIST" | xargs kdialog --menu title
```

Note I used the exact strings you tried. Each string happens to be in a format `xargs` parses as you expect. See `man 1 xargs` to learn the details.

Your question is tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash). In Bash you don't need `printf`, you can use the following syntax:

```bsh
<<<"$LIST" xargs kdialog --menu title
```

---

Note: [avoid uppercase names for variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42849/108618). If you get used to them then sooner or later you will possibly change `PATH` or another important environment variable in some script and the rest of the script will fail.